# Regular expression for validating a SharePoint site address

Tags: development, validation, regex

I am trying validate an input from a text box and I want to make sure it is a well formed SharePoint address, e.g. http://site/ Does anyone have a regular expression that can do this or another method of validating the input address?

Most the regex's I have found on the web validate normal website addresses, e.g. http://www.site.com which I don't want.

Edit: I am using C#

Comment: Are you doing this with JavaScript?

Comment: I am writing this in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a regex, but it will check to see if its a valid uri which will get the job done. And I don't like regex's to begin with :)

```
        Uri uri = null;
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(siteCollectionURL, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) || null == uri)
        {
            //Invalid URL
            return false;
        }
```